# MySQL - number connection reached

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

In my web host I have a limit of 15000 connections per hour. How can I check the number of connections already reached? Is there any way?
I need a solution in PHP mysqli query, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. In MySQL you can query

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
```

to get full listing of server's stats. There you will see what you needed:

- [Connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections) (total connections successful or not)
- [Thread_connected](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Threads_connected) (total active connections, useful if you want to check active connections)

but you can not get created connections per last hour natively. Instead you can request this data each hour and store previous value, so your desired count would be difference between actual and previous `Connections` values.

*hint*: to get only desired variable you can query like:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Connections'
```