# max_user_connections Error in my website?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i have a website with Codeigniter Suddenly
i got this Error:

> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (42000/1226): User 'USER' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 30)

my host is Godaddy

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - number connection reached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296399/mysql-number-connection-reached)

Comment: i can't understand this but

Comment: Connections := 126037

Comment: You should contact Godaddy about this.